# Problem with Pylint executing the code in VScode/Linux

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm practising Python programminng with VScode in my Solus budgie laptop. I have Python-extension installed in VScode and Python3 + Pylint installed in Linux.

I wrote a program that makes thumbnail pictures from all the pictures in one folder. It works just fine when I run the code from terminal but when I run it from VScode, it executes the code but doesn't create thumbnail pictures, so something is wrong. Otherwise Pylint works in VScode but it just doesn't execute the commands it is supposed to. Also, programs that doesn't use Pylint work as they should on VScode.

I also tried running the code from Thonny and it works just fine.

I included console output from VScode when I run the code:

```
[Extension Host] Info Python Extension: 2019-09-27 17:51:34: Shell path 'Python Debug Console' (at t (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.9.34911/out/client/extension.js:1:6300))
workbench.desktop.main.js:16592 [Extension Host] Info Python Extension: 2019-09-27 17:51:34: Shell path identified as shell 'other' (at t (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.9.34911/out/client/extension.js:1:6300))
workbench.desktop.main.js:16592 [Extension Host] Info Python Extension: 2019-09-27 17:51:34: Terminal name 'Python Debug Console' identified as shell 'other' (at t (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.9.34911/out/client/extension.js:1:6300))
workbench.desktop.main.js:16592 [Extension Host] Info Python Extension: 2019-09-27 17:51:34: [object Object]. Shell identified as other (Terminal name is Python Debug Console) (at t (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.9.34911/out/client/extension.js:1:6300))
workbench.desktop.main.js:16592 [Extension Host] Info Python Extension: 2019-09-27 17:51:34: Shell identified as 'other' (at t (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.9.34911/out/client/extension.js:1:6300))
workbench.desktop.main.js:16592 [Extension Host] Info Python Extension: 2019-09-27 17:51:34: Using default OS shell (at t (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.9.34911/out/client/extension.js:1:6300))
2workbench.desktop.main.js:16592 [Extension Host] Info Python Extension: 2019-09-27 17:51:34: Cached data exists getEnvironmentVariables, /home/user/Programming/Python_exercises (at t (/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.9.34911/out/client/extension.js:1:6300))
```

And this is output from extensions log:

```
[2019-09-27 17:48:21.091] [exthost] [info] extension host started
[2019-09-27 17:48:21.126] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.python {"startup":false,"activationEvent":"onLanguage:python"}
[2019-09-27 17:48:21.126] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///usr/share/vscode/resources/app/extensions/python/dist/pythonMain
[2019-09-27 17:48:21.130] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-python.python {"startup":false,"activationEvent":"onLanguage:python"}
[2019-09-27 17:48:21.131] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///home/joonas/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.9.34911/out/client/extension
[2019-09-27 17:48:21.931] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.debug-auto-launch {"startup":true,"activationEvent":"*"}
[2019-09-27 17:48:21.932] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///usr/share/vscode/resources/app/extensions/debug-auto-launch/dist/extension
[2019-09-27 17:48:21.935] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.emmet {"startup":true,"activationEvent":"*"}
[2019-09-27 17:48:21.935] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///usr/share/vscode/resources/app/extensions/emmet/dist/extension
[2019-09-27 17:48:21.990] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.git {"startup":true,"activationEvent":"*"}
[2019-09-27 17:48:21.990] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///usr/share/vscode/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/main
[2019-09-27 17:48:22.122] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.merge-conflict {"startup":true,"activationEvent":"*"}
[2019-09-27 17:48:22.122] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///usr/share/vscode/resources/app/extensions/merge-conflict/dist/extension
[2019-09-27 17:48:22.521] [exthost] [info] eager extensions activated
[2019-09-27 17:51:33.510] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.debug-server-ready {"startup":false,"activationEvent":"onDebugResolve"}
[2019-09-27 17:51:33.510] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///usr/share/vscode/resources/app/extensions/debug-server-ready/dist/extension
```

Comment: add the error log and more details describing the error

Comment: I added some logs which I could find.